# How to redirect url using .htaccess so that it wont look inside folder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have this url `www.sample.com/news-center/details/idparameter` and

I want to redirect it to the this url `www.sample.com/news-center/details.html/idparameter`

I have a news-center folder and a `details.html` file, the rules below goes inside a details folder. How do I rewrite it so it will go to `details.html` inside the news-center folder?

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.html [NC,N]
RewriteRule ^news-center/?$ news-center/index.html [NC,N]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

I tried adding the code below but it didn't work.

```
RewriteRule ^/details/(.+)\.html$ details.html [R]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the code below and it worked! though my angular doesn't work now but 
 my initial problem is now solved.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.html [NC,N]
RewriteRule ^news-center/?$ news-center/index.html [NC,N]
RewriteRule ^news-center/details/([^\.]+)$ news-center/details.html [NC,N]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.html [L]
RewriteRule ^news-center/?$ /news-center/index.html [L]
RewriteRule ^news-center/details/(.+)\.html$ /news-center/details.html/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It's not working as expected. I updated my question, please see above. thanks

Comment: if you want to match URI contains news-center folder , htaccess file should be either in root or the folder itself not in its sub folder

Comment: htaccess file is in my root forder, `parameter`changes base on id.

Comment: When I added your code to my ` .htaccess` it returned `404 not found` on vwww.sample.com/news-center/` which redirects to `www.sample.com/news-center/index.html`(this was working before) and when I try to go to `www.sample.com/news-center/details/idparameter` it redirects to a full path folder

Comment: Ok , if your code is fine and you want only add this line RewriteRule ^news-center/details/(.+)\.html$ /news-center/details.html/$1 [R=301,L] add it and test , clear browser cache first

Comment: does not work for me, it calls the full path folder instead but thank you for the effort.